# Can I delete a item from std::list based on pointer value?

Tags: c++, stl

This code is written on fly, plz ignore syntax mistakes if any.

```
std::list<MY_STRUCT> myList;

MY_STRUCT theStruct;

myList.push_back( theStruct );
myList.push_back( theStruct );

// assume I store the pointer of the last item (the 2nd item in this case).
MY_STRUCT * item2 = &myList.back();

// I added another item
myList.push_back( theStruct );

// now I want to delete item2 that I stored bases on its pointer.
// Can myList.remove_if(...) help if so how?
```

I want to delete the middle item in the list by its pointer (assume I have the pointer value).

I know I can iterate through the list and look for this pointer but is there a better way? Does STL provide a function to do it..Can I use remove_if() in this case to delete the item?

Comment: seems you meant `MY_STRUCT * item2 = &mylist.back();`

Comment: If you make `item2` be an iterator rather than a pointer then you can use `list::erase` to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks Andy T, I fixed that in original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, `list::remove_if` uses whatever condition you give it. For example

```
template <typename T>
struct AddressIs {
    T *ptr;
    AddressIs(T *ptr) : ptr(ptr) {}
    bool operator()(const T &object) const {
        return ptr == &object;
    }
};

myList.remove_if(AddressIs<MY_STRUCT>(item2));
```

Mankarse's point is good though - if you can use an iterator instead of a pointer to identify the item you're interested in, then you don't need to mess about with this.

Beware also that we're relying here on the fact that the address of an item in a `list` stays the same forever. That isn't always true of all collections, for example `vector` might have to relocate all the data when you call `push_back`. If it does, then your middle item is no longer pointed to by `item2`. Each collection documents which operations can invalidate iterators and/or references to elements.

Comment: I get compiler error C2535: 'bool std::binder1st<_Fn2>::operator ()(const MY_STRUCT &) const' : member function already defined or declared

Comment: @zadane: oops, I forgot that `std::bind1st` can't cope with a function that has a reference type as the second parameter. There are other ways to write a predicate, though, I'll add one.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of keeping a pointer to the object you want to remove, why not keep an iterator?

```
std::list<MY_STRUCT>::iterator item2 = --mylist.end();
```

The remove_if algorithm doesn't actually remove anything, it just shifts stuff around. It has no knowledge of the container that the iterators point to. Of course the member function remove_if of std::list is a different thing altogether as pointed out in the comments.

Comment: "doesn't actually remove anything" - you're thinking of `std::remove_if`, this is `list::remove_if`. Don't blame me, I didn't pick the names ;-)

Comment: @Steve, thanks for pointing that out. It's tough to keep track of all the facilities C++ provides.

Comment: Make sure the list isn't empty before decrementing `end()`.

Comment: @Mike Seymour, the same would be true of calling `back()` so this isn't any less safe than the original code.

Comment: Does the iterator stays the same (like the pointer value I am using) in the std::list if more items are added or deleted? If that is the case than I could store iterator instead but the only item I really need is the data pointer though.

Comment: @zadane: In the case of std::list (and map/set), yes.  For other containers (vector), no.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of getting the `back` item, you could get the `end` iterator, make sure it's not `begin`, decrement by one to point to the last item, and then `erase` that iterator directly whenever you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think remove_if is a little bit of overkill for what zadane is trying to do. All that needs to be accomplished is to save the location or value of an item in order to delete that specific item later.

As Mark suggested you can store the iterator to the object and use it to delete the item with an erase call, like below:

```
MY_STRUCT struct;
myList.push_back(struct);
myList.push_back(struct);
std::list<MY_STRUCT>::iterator del_it = myList.end() - 1;
myList.erase(del_it);
```

Or, if your structure has the == operator defined for MY_STRUCT, you can store the value of the object itself and use the remove method

```
MY_STRUCT struct1;
MY_STRUCT struct2;
myList.push_back(struct1);
myList.push_back(struct2);
myList.remove(struct2);
```

Of course if you make your list a list of pointers then you don't have to worry about the == operator as it is already defined for pointer types. Just make sure that if you're iterating through the list and call erase, you need to update your iterator with the returned value.

Also, the remove method removes all elements of the passed value, so if you only want to remove 1 item at a time save the iterator and not the value.

This code is untested so I welcome any corrections.